# PHP header redirect not working correctly

Tags: php

I’m trying to re-direct a user to a new page once their login credentials have been confirmed, however for some reason the redirect won’t work. It appears to be related to my `header.php` file. When I include the redirect **before** this it works; however if I try and include it after this file, it doesn’t work.

I’ve tried adding the redirect to `header.php` itself and when I include it directly before the `<html>` tag, it works (well I say works, but it gives an error which is more than it does otherwise; `Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.`).

I’ve checked all files for whitespace etc, which has led me to locate the issue being related to `header.php`. What is the issue with `header.php` that’s causing this, taking into consideration it initiates *before* the HTML tag but not when placed *after*?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>css/property.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700" type="text/css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="header">

        <div class="wrapper">

            <h1 class="branding-title"><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>">Some title</a></h1>

            <ul class="nav">
                <?php
                  /* list items with a class of "on" indicate the current section; those links 
                   * are underlined in the CSS to communicate that back to the site visitor;
                   * the $section variable is set in each individual file
                   */
                ?>
                <li class="shirts <?php if ($section == "shirts") { echo "on"; } ?>"><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>shirts/">Shirts</a></li>
                <li class="contact <?php if ($section == "contact") { echo "on"; } ?>"><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>contact/">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="search <?php if ($section == "search") { echo "on"; } ?>"><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>search/">Search</a></li>
                <li class="cart"><a target="paypal" href="XYZ">Shopping Cart</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="content">
```

Comment: Could you post the contents of `header.php`?

Comment: The error message says that the redirect *is* working. you created a circular loop however. Use `wget` or `curl` to find out.

Comment: Added the header.php. I want to use the header, but use it on my main page where i include the header.php file - although the header does work when i put it before the `<html>` tag, it doesn't work elsewhere.

Comment: where is the redirect?

Comment: I removed it, but when testing i added it directly before the `<html>` tag and it worked, added at ANY point after the opening `<html>` tag nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> although the header does work when i put it before the  tag, it doesn't work elsewhere.

This is actually your problem. Headers can only be set before the body is sent. You just need to keep the redirect above any page content.

This is how a HTTP response is structured:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Header-1: bacon
Header-2: more bacon

<html>
<head>
  <title>Bacon</title>
...
```

A redirect is a HTTP header, specifically the `Location` header. You can't set this after you've already sent data (well you can but it's weird and complicated). You should also be finding errors somewhere in your code, assuming you have error reporting on somewhere.

As for your other issue...

> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

That's because you're redirecting in a loop (ie redirecting to a redirect that redirects back to itself). If your redirect is in `header.php`, assuming you're including that on the page you're redirecting too, that's probably the issue.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. I wasn't sure what exactly what was declared the header, you've just cleared that up in your answer. I decided to create a function that incorporates Javascript to redirect.